# Post with flutter exception invalid argument no host specified in URI

Tags: android, flutter, http, dart, post

I've been trying to post my data from this code and it keeps telling me that there were no host specified URI. The other case in stack overflow keeps telling to use http or https, but I'm already using it from the start and it doesn't work. Could someone tell me is there any logic error or something. PS: the GroupCode need to be returned as a list[''].

```
  String sourceDocType = 'STATUS_UPDATE';
  List listTampungan = [];

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    news = TextEditingController();
    getData();
  }

  Future<List> getData() async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    name = prefs.getString('employeeName');
    id = prefs.getString('sessionId');
    location = prefs.getString('location');
    groupCode = prefs.getString('groupCode');
    var tampungan = [id, name, location, groupCode];
    return tampungan;
  }

  Future<http.Response> postNewsFeed() async {
    var url = "http:xxxx?";
    var response = await http.post(url,
        body: json.encode({
          "Type": type,
          "strEmpNo": id,
          "strNews": news,
          "strPrivacyType": privacyType,
          "strCreatedBy": id,
          "strGroupCode": ['$groupCode'],
          "strSourceDocType": sourceDocType,
          "strEncodedImage": null,
        }));
    return response;
  }
```

This is the button where I call the method:

```
        ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              postNewsFeed();
            },
            child: Text('SAVE')),
```

Comment: Your `url='http:xxxx?'` doesn't make any sense. It's probably throwing the error because it can't find a **host** in the url neither can it recognize if the url has **http or https**

Comment: What url are you trying to post to? Also does `htttp.post()` require a `Uri uri` or a `String url`?

Comment: @AbdurRafaySaleem Hi, this is my http http://111.11.11.11:111/Services/SocMed/SocMedSvc.ashx, I've tried it in the postman and the data got inserted into the API.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/http) of the `http` package, all of the methods have been changed to now take an argument of type `Uri url` instead of `String url`.

### Simple url

The `Uri` class has a specific format and a normal `String url` needs to be parsed using `Uri.parse`. Make the following modifications:

```dart
var url = Uri.parse("http://111.11.11.11:111/Services/SocMed/SocMedSvc.ashx");
```

### Url with paramaters

If you want to pass query parameters as well then use one of the static methods `.http()`/`.https()` depending on your url.

```dart
var _authority = '111.11.11.11:111';
var _path = '/Services/SocMed/SocMedSvc.ashx';
var _params = {};
var url = Uri.http(_authority, _path, _params);
```

Comment: Thanks.. I'm using this method using .http